# How to avoid 'no such file to load -- map_by_method' script/console with bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, bundler, irb

I am running *rails 2.3.10* with *bundler*. I use *rvm*, in global gemsets usually I put the gems useful for the irb. By default I had these there: map_by_method, what_methods, ap, net-http-spy, hirb, looksee, pp, wirble.

When I start irb, the gems it needs are avalaible for it, and the things look as they should. However, when I start script/console, it cannot reach the gems in the current rvm gemset only those which are defined in `Gemfile`. I get message `no such file to load -- map_by_method`. Obviously I do not want to put those irb specific files to my `Gemfile`.

Do you know some way, how to convince script/console to use also gems outside bundler?

Answer (score 1):

bundler will never use any gem that is not defined in the Gemfile. If those gems are for development use only consider adding them to the Gemfile in a group called :development

Comment: Sounds like this is just a 'no'.  There should be a way.  For instance when you want to load a console to the production environment but want  to load 'hirb'.

Comment: not that I've seen. If it aint in the Gemfile, too bad so sad.

Answer (score 0):

You can hand-require gems from within script console if you need them:

```
$ script/console
=> require 'rubygems'
=> require 'mygem'
=> include 'MyGem::Stuff'
```