# no such file to load -- map_by_method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, console, bundler, irb

This question was asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408313/how-to-avoid-no-such-file-to-load-map-by-method-script-console-with-bundler), but can't say that the answer helps me.  I am using Rails 3.1.3.  When I run rails console on my local dev machine, I get the following message:

```
no such file to load -- map_by_method
```

The message doesn't prevent the irb session from launching, so it's benign. But I'd like to get rid of it.  At one point in time I had the map_by_method gem installed, but I removed it from the Gemfile and gemset -- yet the message still appears.  Any idea how to vanquish it?

Comment: there might be some causes for this: 1. there might be some other gem which has it as a dependency, 2. you might have a require 'map_by_method' in your code 3. you might have a require in your .irbrc

Comment: how do you modify the .irbrc?

Comment: like any other file. have a look at this example http://matthewhutchinson.net/2010/9/19/rails-3-bash-aliases-and-irbrc-configs

Comment: That was it.  Please add your comment as an answer so I can award.

Comment: glad it helped. i added it as an answer, you could have also marked my comment as helpful, wich is equaly awarding ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there might be some causes for this:

1. there might be some other gem which has it as a dependency
2. you might have a require 'map_by_method' in your code
3. you might have a require in your .irbrc

the .irbrc can be located in your user home or in the current working directory.
have a look at an example .irbrc here: http://matthewhutchinson.net/2010/9/19/rails-3-bash-aliases-and-irbrc-configs

Answer (score 0):

Probably the gem map_by_method has done some permanent changes on your system. Try re-installing it. It should fixed your problem. Same thing happened to me once. If it doesn't, try specifying it in development section of gemfile.